# Qt Lang environment?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qtcore, qcoreapplication

I Have got an issue concerning Qt Locale environment when I execute the following code

```
QApplication(argc,argv) ;
float f = 42.5f
std::cout << std::to_string(f) ; // prints 42,5
```

Even if my computer got its locale to french I'd like my program to be compiled with us standard printing format (i.e. `42.5` ). Is there a way to do that with a compiler option ?

Comment: Qt has a feature called [string builder](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#more-efficient-string-construction), which also uses `operator%`. Now I think if that were the issue, it would produce an entirely different result, but maybe worth looking into?

Comment: @lethal-guitar I take a look, thx

Comment: @leJon: why would you? That is not relevant to your float issue. Does this issue occur with `QString::number(f, 'f')`, too?

Comment: @LaszloPapp: No, it do not occurs with QString::number. Do you know what causes this behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QLocale>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QCoreApplication coreApplication(argc, argv);
    float f = 42.5f;
    qDebug() << QString::number(f, 'f', 1);
    QLocale locale;
    qDebug() << locale.toString(f, 'f', 1);
    return coreApplication.exec();
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

#### Output

```
"42.5"
"42.5"
```

This may be interesting for you:

> [QString QString::number(double n, char format = 'g', int precision = 6) [static]](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#number-2)
>
> Returns a string equivalent of the number n, formatted according to the specified format and precision. See Argument Formats for details.
>
> Unlike QLocale::toString(), this function does not honor the user's locale settings.

Comment: Yes I know, but you are using Qt conversion and I need to use std::to_string

Comment: @leJon: std::string is raw string basically with hidden memory management for you. Its task is not to deal with localized strings. That is what QLocale exists for.

Comment: Ok for that but I can't solve my problem using QString and Qt printing. I use a templated library that generate text file. Outside of a qt application this lead to us printing but in a qt application I've got the french printing that bother me.

Comment: You have to use QApplication, but you do not want to use QString and QLocale? Now, that is just strange.

Comment: It's not so strange if the library is a third-party library that does not use Qt.

Comment: I make a frontend to a library which is without qt. The library uses std::string to print some real values. That's where the issue is. The file generated by the library called from qt gives this strange issues

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: there is no third-party code in here, and even if there was, a library should _not_ print to the output.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: the problem is the same when printing in file. The std::cout was there just for the example

Comment: @lejon: uh... 1) You are getting newer and newer requirements. 2) The library should be revamped not to print anything to the standard output, etc. That is very very nasty. It should be up to the application developers. 3) It is not really rocket science, please read upon std::locale. You can specify the locale, which you could read from the settings. Anyway, good luck with all this. You keep adding new requirements. Now we are at file writing in libraries ...

Comment: I propose to close the post whereas lot's of requirement are getting newer -- I was just trying to understand what causes this behavior, as you said this is not rocket science, there is a reason...